# how to replace Machine Name with Domain name in WCF Service wsdl link

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis-6

wasnt sure quite what to name the question but the problem is as follows:

I am deploying a WCF service on IIS 6 which is to be consumed by an external source.
the box that it is on is externally hosted but has a DC so is effectively on my network ('**mydomain**'), internally it's called '**prod**' say.
the service need to run over SSL so we got an SSL cert for the domain the service will respond to: service.oursite.com lets say

DNS has all filtered through and I can indeed hit the service on 
https://service.oursite.com/service.svc
and it kicks out the little svcutil link .
the problem is that the address that the link points to is not 
https://service.oursite.com/service.svc?wsdl as I would hope

it is instead

https://prod.mydomain.com/service.svc?wsdl
so of course the SSL bails as the cert is not for that 
and if i click through to the wsdl all the schemaLocation links are wrong, again pointing to the internal rather than external name

**question is:**
why is it doing that?
and 
how do i stop it doing that?

is it a matter of adding something in the config? (please say yes :))

any help as ever most gratefully received

if it helps here is the config

```
<services>
  <service name="CBBookingService.CBBookingService" behaviorConfiguration="CBBookingService.CBBookingServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" contract="CBBookingService.ICBBookingService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicSecurity" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="TransportSecurity" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <!--https-->
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CBBookingService.CBBookingServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `<useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>` service behavior, and you should get the behavior you want:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CBBookingService.CBBookingServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
      <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: this looks like the best option but sadly I am using .net 3.5 so it doesnt like that element. I will do from now on when I use .net 4 - thanks

Comment: Can't test it now, but I think this was the reason I couldn't get some WCF services working on a shared hosting server that was using an SSL cert. I think this may solve that problem. Did verify it works on a .NET 4 WCF service (internally hosted).

Answer (score 2):

You can change it in your configuration.

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"  
 externalMetadataLocation="https://service.oursite.com/service.svc?wsdl"/>
```

or use https://stackoverflow.com/a/14592767/2012977 for asp.net v4 or later.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the answers
unfortunately I am using .net 3.5 so the answers below do not work
I ended up doing this

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="CBBookingService.CBBookingService" behaviorConfiguration="CBBookingService.CBBookingServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="https://service.oursite.com/CBBookingService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" contract="CBBookingService.ICBBookingService" name="SSL" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicSecurity" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="TransportSecurity" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <!--https-->
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CBBookingService.CBBookingServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpsGetUrl="https://service.oursite.com/CBBookingService.svc/SSL" /> 
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks! Your answer helped me solve my problem